# SQL Sub-query (Where In)

Tags: sql, subquery, where-in

I get an error with my sub-query and am not seeing what I am doing wrong. Sub-query works on it's on. There Where-In is obviously what is the problem. Also tried EXISTS.

```
select [ID NUMBER], [PERNO], [TITLE], [INITIALS], [SURNAME], [DATE OF BIRTH] 
from dbo.[DATASEPT002] 
WHERE [ID NUMBER] IN 
( SELECT [ID NUMBER], COUNT([PERSALNO]) AS COUNTOF 
FROM [dbo].[DATASEPT] 
GROUP BY [ID NUMBER] HAVING COUNT([PERSALNO]) >1 )
```

Comment: The subquery redundantly returns `COUNT([PERSALNO])`.

Comment: I forgot to add. I also tried to only select ID number from the sub-query, so the sub-query is only ID numbers but haven't been able to do that either. Thx for formatting.

Comment: Please include the ***actual query*** you use with the ***actual error / issue*** you encounter.  If you have tried two or more queries then provide them ***all***, each with the associated error / issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have two columns in the subquery.  Only one can be used for the `IN` comparison:

```
select [ID NUMBER], [PERNO], [TITLE], [INITIALS], [SURNAME], [DATE OF BIRTH] 
from dbo.[DATASEPT002] t
WHERE [ID NUMBER] IN (SELECT [ID NUMBER]
                      FROM [dbo].[DATASEPT] 
                      GROUP BY [ID NUMBER] 
                      HAVING COUNT([PERSALNO]) > 1
                     );
```

However, I would expression this more typically using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by persalno) as cnt
      from DATASEPT002 t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: There are 2 different tables Gordon, so your second example is not correct

Comment: @user4242750 - Then the comment on your OP is misleading / incorrect.  Because the only change to your query is that this one does `only select ID number from the sub-query`, about which you said `but haven't been able to do that either`.

Comment: I see the ambiguity, apologies. @MatBailie